# How to select all columns except one?

Tags: php, xml, database

How can I select all columns in my database except the one the user is on?

I want to have all data posted in my xml page, but not the line that shows the current users info

```
<?php
    include_once 'test-dbconnect.php';
    function parseToXML($htmlStr)
    {
    $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
    return $xmlStr;
    }


    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    // Start XML file, echo parent node
    echo '<markers>';

        $sql = "select * from tbl_users WHERE username != '".$row['username']."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($DBcon, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($DBcon));

        //create an array
        $user_data = array();
        while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $user_data[] = $row;

            echo '<marker ';
            echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['username']) . '" ';
            echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
            echo 'latitude="' . $row['latitude'] . '" ';
            echo 'longitude="' . $row['longitude'] . '" ';
            echo '/>';
        }


        //close the db connection
        mysqli_close($DBcon);

    // End XML file
    echo '</markers>';

    ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to exclude column or row? You wrote that you want to exclude row but your code shows the opposite.

Comment: @ElChupacabra I want to exclude one column, and to be more spefic i want the column with the data about the current user to be excluded
what do you mean about my code shiws the oppsite